# Launching exe by clicking on the windows desktop widget

Tags: windows, widget

I have created a windows widget and I want to launch my executable when the widget is clicked. Currently my widget has a button that just increments a counter.

This is my counter template json string.

```
const std::string countWidgetTemplate = R"(
{                                                                     
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",                                         
    "body": [                                                         
        {                                                               
            "type": "TextBlock",                                    
            "text": "You have clicked the button ${count} times"    
        },
        {
             "text":"Rendering Only if Medium",
             "type":"TextBlock",
             "$when":"${$host.widgetSize==\"medium\"}"
        }                                                            
    ],                                                                  
    "actions": [                                                      
        {  
            "type": "Action.Execute",                            
            "title": "Increment",                                   
            "verb": "inc"                                           
        }                       
                                            
    ],  
                                                                       
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.5"                                                
})";
```

This is my OnActionInvoked() method.

```
void WidgetProvider::OnActionInvoked(winrt::WidgetActionInvokedArgs actionInvokedArgs)
{
    auto verb = actionInvokedArgs.Verb();
    if (verb == L"inc")
    {
        auto widgetId = actionInvokedArgs.WidgetContext().Id();
       
        if (const auto iter = RunningWidgets.find(widgetId); iter != RunningWidgets.end())
        {
            auto& localWidgetInfo = iter->second;
            // Increment the count
            localWidgetInfo.customState++;
            UpdateWidget(localWidgetInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on how to launch my exe on clicking the widget?
I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/widgets/implement-widget-provider-win32) sample project.

Comment: Inside the `if (verb == L"inc") { ... }`, launch your exe instead of updating the widget.

Comment: I tried using ShellExecute() method to launch my exe inside the if{}, but it throws a linkage error.                                                                                                             
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ShellExecuteW referenced in function "public: void __cdecl WidgetProvider::OnActionInvoked(struct winrt::Microsoft::Windows::Widgets::Providers::WidgetActionInvokedArgs)" (?OnActionInvoked@WidgetProvider@@QEAAXUWidgetActionInvokedArgs@Providers@Widgets@Windows@Microsoft@winrt@@@Z)

Comment: All I needed to do was link shell32.lib and the shellexecute method worked. Include this at the top : #pragma comment(lib,"Shell32.lib")